Why do we write the work of elastic force as $Fdr=-xrdr$? why do we put negative sign?
in the irodov fundamental of mechanics its written that work done by elastic force is $-xrdr$ for a displacement of $dr$. why do put negative sign?

Please type out the relevant section of the book. Or at the very least state the section/page number. There is no context at all here. What is x? What is r? Do you expect us to read your mind??

If the work done by a force is negative it means that the force is taking energy from the system. In the case of an elastic force it will be storing the energy as potential energy. Of course what is actually happening depends on what $xr$ and $dr$ are.

i am very sorry for any inconvenience i have caused in this questions and i appreciate all the responses which have been put up. it is Irodov fundamental of mechanics, pg no. 74 and topic3.2 work and power.

The negative sign is because the force $\vec F$ is in the opposite direction to the displacement $\vec r$. There is an implicit assumption here that the value of the elastic constant $x$ is positive i.e. $\vec F = -x\vec r$.

thanks for your answer
